# Is there a way to check if my proxy is online?

Tags: c

I need to know if I can access internet from my proxy, I'm doing this now:

```
if((system("wget -q www.google.it -O /dev/null")); // I don't have access.
```

Is there a better way to solve this problem? Is there a function in C?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try to connect to the proxy directly with a socket ?

Comment: I'm the proxy, I mean, I need to know if my computer can give access to web pages to other computers in my network, if not, I must change some config files.

Comment: Then connect to `www.google.it` on port 80 with a socket. Lookup `gethostbyname`, `socket` and `connect`.

Comment: You may also be interested in [Beej's guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone loves this guide.

http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

It'll help you learn how to get to grips with networking programming in C very easily.

Comment: Thank you for the link to that guide :P